# hide elements in an iframe from the parent when the iframe has no id

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, shadowbox

The url is http://oxfordgenetics.com/plasmid-builder and the iframe comes from the "product details" link on each builder group. What I need to do is hide some of the elements in the shadowbox that appears when this link is clicked.

I have tried all of the usual remedies (both jQuery and js) without success as most of them latch onto the iframe using its ID which doesn't exist here.

Same domain of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around it by having the code below test if it was a 'modal' box or not with an arbitrary ID that was only in the 'modal' window:

```
var element = document.getElementById('system-message-container'); 
if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
{
       document.getElementById('cartarea').style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know the iframe will be in the shadowbox, which has an id of `sbox-content`. So this should work:

```
var $iframe = jQuery('#sbox-content iframe')
```

Comment: I have tried over 30 different variations, many of which were from the above. Can this be done? It is so easy to access the parent from the iframe, but not the other way around when one doesn't have an id.

Comment: Whether an element has an id or not shouldn't be relevant so long as you can select the element.

Comment: Well I first tried:jQuery('#sbox-content iframe #cartarea').hide(); without success, then var $iframe = jQuery('#sbox-content iframe #cartarea'); $iframe.hide(); - which are probably the same things without success.