# hide elements in an iframe via css/jquery

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I have a widget that I load via iframe you can see the code here http://www.coininfo.com/gold-silver-platium-palladium-banner-widget.php

What I want to do is hide two elements (the logo and also the date and time). 
via css/jquery however I am not able to figure it out.

Is there anyway to hide these two elements in this ifame and if so how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+elements+in+iframe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129487/is-there-a-way-hide-elements-in-iframe-src-page?s=2|2.0600 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465655/hide-elements-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-when-the-iframe-has-no-id?s=5|1.4552  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30566295/embed-website-in-an-iframe-and-hide-certain-elements?s=8|0.6351 etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide elements in iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824507/hide-elements-in-iframe)